# VideoJS, invalid source?

Tags: internet-explorer, video, html5-video, video.js

Currently running VideoJS 4.5.1, on IE 11, when you press the play button on a video, it comes back "Invalid Source". Does anyone know what that means? Check path and video, and on various browsers. Only happens on IE 11.

Comment: Does html5 video work in the browser?  I'm facing a similar situation on a custom (old) player the company I work has been using.  some reason win7 / IE 11 on a clients computer does not play HTML5 videos and so it fails playing.

Comment: You should try updating to video.js v4.6. The error reporting is a little cleaner there. "Invalid Source" isn't one of the [standard html5 errors](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#error-codes), so I'm not exactly sure where that's coming from. It's possible the video is encoded in a way that only IE can't handle. Can you provide any more details about what video format(s) you're using?

Comment: @heff, not sure how the video was formatted. I was just handed a URL to plugin. I'll check and see if I can get some more info.

Comment: @heff, took your advice and upgraded to version 4.6 and videos are working. Not sure what was wrong with 4.5, but nonetheless it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Spoke too soon. Videos aren't working on IE10+. Video returns this message, "Video could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed, or because the format is not supported".

Comment: I guess I was wrong. I was testing through Browserstack and it seems to be a problem on their end.

Comment: @Ken Fyrstenberg - I see you've a `videojs` tag to a few old questions. That's a dupe of the established `video.js` tag - mind voting for the tag synonym to help clear these up? http://stackoverflow.com/tags/video.js/synonyms